# Django @login_required not redirecting to login page

Tags: django, django-class-based-views, login-required

I am using class based views in Django. @login_required decorator is not redirecting to login page. It still shows the profile page.

```
class ProfileView(TemplateView):
template_name='profile.html'

@login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/')
def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProfileView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Can anyone help me. I m new to Django and any help would be appreciated.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 5):

**You need to apply a `method_decorator` first and then pass it the `login_required` function decorator.**

A method on a class isn’t quite the same as a standalone function, so you can’t just apply a function decorator to the method. **You need to transform it into a method decorator first.**

To make it more clear, Django's view decorators return a function with a signature `(request, *args, **kwargs)` but for class based-views, the signature should be of the form `(self, request, *args, **kwargs)`. Now, what the `method_decorator` does is that it transforms the first signature to the second.

From docs on [decorating Class-based Views:](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/class-based-views/intro/#decorating-class-based-views)

> The `method_decorator` decorator transforms a function decorator into
>   a method decorator so that it can be used on an instance method.

```
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator

class ProfileView(TemplateView):
    template_name='profile.html'

    @method_decorator(login_required(login_url='/accounts/login/'))
    def dispatch(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(ProfileView, self).dispatch(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but it is still not redirecting to the login page.

Comment: I have configured `LOGIN_URL` and `LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL` in settings too.

Comment: Whats the value for those 2 settings?

Comment: `LOGIN_URL ='/accounts/login/'  
LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = '/accounts/profile/'`

Comment: I don't think defining it in settings should be an issue. Since the login url is same as defined in settings, you can do `@method_decorator(login_required)`. If the user isn’t logged in, it will  redirect to `settings.LOGIN_URL`.

Comment: But it's still not redirecting.

Comment: Is use of dispatch a problem. Should I use some other class based view ?

Comment: No, that should not be an issue. This might be silly but have you restarted the server?

Comment: An Update. I tried to use login_required in urls.py too. Still not redirecting

Comment: You can try `url(r'^my_url$', login_required(ProfileView.as_view()))` if this works.

Comment: Tried that. Still not redirecting

Answer (score 0):

When using class-based views, it's preferred to use the LoginRequiredMixin rather than the @login_required decorator. It performs essentially the same function.

```py
    class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
        template_name='profile.html'
```

Comment: Hmm I'm trying to do login required, but do not redirect to login page hehe

Comment: LoginRequiredMixin extends AccessMixin which has a method handle_no_permission which is called when the user has no access. This method checks for a class member called raise_exception which defaults to False. Setting this True will raise an error instead of redirecting.

    class ProfileView(LoginRequiredMixin, TemplateView):
        template_name='profile.html'
        raise_exception=True